# Cordova file create directory not working

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following code and for some reason its not working as intended even though the success callback is being called.

Here is what I know is working currently.

- Camera is able to take image and storage it in the app's folder cache
- When going to create the directory in `resolveonsuccess` function the directory doesnt seem to be created, I physically check the folder on the app and it not created.
- Once it renames the file and moves it, I dont get any error callbacks, only success.
- After file is moved, it is no longer in the cache, is the file being moved to a hidden folder?

Any help would be much appreciated.

> ```
> function capturePhoto() {
>         sessionStorage.removeItem('imagepath');
>         // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
>         navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
>             quality: 50,
>             destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
>         });
>     }
> ```

```
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
         console.log(imageURI);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var imgProfile = document.getElementById('imgProfile');

        // Show the captured photo
        // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        imgProfile.src = imageURI;
        if (sessionStorage.isprofileimage == 1) {
            getLocation();
        }
        movePic(imageURI);
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function movePic(file) {
        console.log("Going to move file");
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError);
    }

    //Callback function when the file system uri has been resolved
    function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        //new file name
        var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
        var myFolderApp = "OCRFolder";

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
                    //The folder is created if doesn't exist
                    fileSys.root.getDirectory(myFolderApp,
                            {create: true, exclusive: false},
                            function (directory) {
                                entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, successMove, resOnError);
                            },
                            resOnError);
                    console.log(fileSys.root);
                },
                resOnError);

    }

    //Callback function when the file has been moved successfully - inserting the complete path
    function successMove(entry) {
        //Store imagepath in session for future use
        // like to store it in database
        console.log("Move was success " +  entry.fullPath);
        sessionStorage.setItem('imagepath', entry.fullPath);
    }

    function resOnError(error) {
        alert(error.code);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by rebuilding my cordova-plugin-file plugin